# EU Blue Card University Degree Requirments

Tags: eu, blue-card, australia

I have an undergraduate degree from a recognized Australian Uni (H+) in IT. For my application, the required documents say I need to bring my university degree, can I bring an original, stamped 'Proof of Qualification' from the university, which has all the required information (name, name of course, completion date, language of instruction)? Or does it have to be the actual original diploma itself?